# Pointer memory usage

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I may be wrong on these facts so correct me!

A pointer points to a memory address, if you went to this memory address you would find a byte ? A pointer also points to the lowest address of the memory segment that it points too, so if it points to an 8 byte memory segment, that starts at 0x0 and ends at 0x7, it will point to 0x0 ?

How does a pointer know the size of memory it points at? So if a pointer points to a segment of memory that is 128 bytes in size and the pointer is cast to a different type, what happens to the size of the memory segment?

Comment: BTW - Your maths is not correct. It would be 0 ... 7 for 8 bytes.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, TBH it really needs a clear definition, some people use inclusive-start-exclusive-end notation to mark a range. Notable example being standard library, where `end()` is "one-past". I wouldn't nitpick but I saw both approaches in use with out clear dominance of neither.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does a pointer know the size of memory it points at ?

It doesn't.

> So if a pointer points to a segment of memory that is 128 bytes in size and the pointer is cast to a different type, what happens to the size of the memory segment ?

The memory's still there, but since you cast away the only information you had about the object residing there, well, y'know. That's it. You don't know.

That's why people use `sizeof` when aliasing objects through a `char*` to get at the underlying bytes:

```
std::ofstream os("some-binary-file");
const double d = 0.1234;

os.write((char*)&d, sizeof(double));
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// 
// Otherwise os.write has no way of knowing how much to write
```

Of course, if you were to chuck around a `double*`, every piece of code using that pointer will assume that it points to one or more "blocks" of memory precisely `sizeof(double)` bytes wide. If it doesn't, then that's your fault.

**tl;dr: Telling the program how many pointee bytes it has to work with is *your* responsibility.**

Comment: Effectively, the *type* of pointer is what is telling the pointer how many bytes it points to.

Comment: @nhgrif: Yet even the type only gets you so far. Consider `double* ptr = new double[200000];`. Now pass `ptr` into a function. Does the function know how many bytes `ptr` points to?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point with arrays.  With arrays, the developer has to keep track of how many indexes.

Comment: Not arrays in general - the size can be retrieved from statically allocated arrays using some template trickery.

Comment: @celticminstrel: Not from a pointer to that array's first element, it can't. This question is about pointers.

Answer (score 2):

> How does a pointer know the size of memory it points at?

Every pointer (apart from `void *`) has an associated type. That type tells the compiler how many bytes to expect at the pointed-to location. When you dereference a pointer, the compiler issues machine instructions which read the appropriate amount of bytes at that location.

It follows that `void *` pointers cannot be dereferenced because they don't carry compile-time information about the size of the pointed-to data.